# How to do PSM with panel data using PanelMatch?

Tags: r, propensity-scores, difference-in-difference, matching

I would greatly appreciate if you could let me know how to use [PanelMatch](https://github.com/insongkim/PanelMatch/tree/master/R) for my dataset. Unfortunately, I couldn't find it's manual so I don't know how to find which firms are matched, how to extract the coefficients of the estimated models, how to report bias before and after matching, and etc..

1. First, I need to do PSM using these variables:

`switch =big4+ lnasset+ leverage+ loss`

2. Then, I should do diff in diff on the matched sample:

`decost= switch+ post_switch +switch*post_switch+ lnaudten +big4 +altmanz +lnasset +lnage +markettobook+ leverage +profit+ tangible+ cashvol`

I also read [this document](https://edge.edx.org/assets/courseware/v1/b8d2a8030b7aa5f2762a464bf7f8b0c7/c4x/BerkeleyX/CEGA101AIE/asset/Module_2.5_Difference_in_Differences.pdf) in Stata. However, in my dataset, the treatment dates are different for each firm. Besides, the treatment could occur more than once for each firm. Therefore, I don’t know how to define "post_switch".

```
id date lnaudten big4 altmanz lnasset lnage    mtob     lev    prof   tang   cavol  switch decost los
1  86  .693147    0   18.4373 12.4689 2.48491 3.69137 .051575 .44427  .999581 .195047  0 .205964  0
1  87  1.09861    0   12.5244 12.7628 2.56495 2.69891 .043572 .559291 .999688 .128583  0 .107817  0
1  88  1.38629    0   14.7922 13.3187 2.63906 3.55144 .037377 .901665 .99897  .045367  0 .085176  0
1  89  1.60944    0   21.6806 13.5282 2.70805 4.4521  .090386 1.00277 .998904 .034365  0 .059932  0
1  90  1.79176    0   16.6034 13.7204 2.77259 3.16585 .077934 1.21371 .999292 .032229  0 .064589  0
1  91  0          0   9.32285 14.0652 2.83321 1.87682 .038984 1.61792 .999376 .019715  1 .086323  0
1  92  .693147    0   29.1306 14.3805 2.89037 3.83173 .030874 3.42558 .999687 .117503  0 .148985  0
1  93  1.09861    0   23.7929 14.5855 2.94444 3.08877 .01225  4.19413 .999862 .171374  0 .181363  0
2  86  1.94591    1   2.67142 13.5351 1.60944 .90438  .031392 .284566 .997711 .172729  0 .116186  0
2  87  2.07944    1   1.85554 13.6068 1.79176 .783169 .037099 .28575  .997862 .055812  0 .137087  0
2  88  2.19723    1   3.25227 13.6162 1.94591 .857463 .046493 .264266 .99788  .052991  0 .174771  0
2  89  2.30258    1   2.46358 13.8247 2.07944 1.00449 .045589 .246997 .998208 .064097  0 .168786  0
2  90  2.3979     1   1.43551 13.8304 2.19723 .791431 .060575 .171494 .998218 .062911  0 .240464  0
2  91  0          0   1.10687 13.7423 2.30258 .532189 .071249 .164944 .998054 .093181  1 .351773  0
2  92  .693147    0   3.39252 13.8668 2.3979  1.80869 .121138 .177533 .998281 .090341  0 .282046  0
2  93  1.09861    0   3.95825 14.0244 2.48491 1.41083 .094626 .162305 .99847  .134091  0 .188627  0
3  86  .693147    0   5.01935 13.0392 3.49651 1.08849 .008833 .275658 .995814 .165765  0 .12684   0
3  87  1.09861    0   8.51978 13.0429 3.52636 .794968 .010574 .349996 .995351 .276396  0 2.49701  0
3  88  1.38629    0   13.1943 13.2777 3.55535 1.36713 .043884 .409195 .996392 .079824  0 .033575  0
3  89  1.60944    0   18.7427 13.4562 3.58352 1.89782 .010373 .42366  .997045 .049833  0 .057621  0
3  90  1.79176    0   20.2185 13.4667 3.61092 1.69264 .016154 .339384 .997148 .133837  0 .133177  0
3  91  0          0   11.1153 13.9098 3.63759 1.50931 .010464 .935899 .998216 .12095   1 .089572  0
3  92  .693147    0   25.7134 14.1341 3.66356 2.41058 .004609 1.06214 .99856  .13175   0 .171943  0
3  93  1.09861    0   29.8983 14.162  3.68888 2.29729 .003891 .902802 .997648 .146949  0 .823985  0
```

Comment: did you try the ?PanelMatch command in R?

Comment: @StatsStudent Thanks. I tried the example codes provided here: https://github.com/insongkim/PanelMatch/tree/master/R. However, as you could see these commands don't report coefficients of the predictors, the reduced bias after matching. I mean some tables like the ones which are illustrated here: https://edge.edx.org/assets/courseware/v1/b8d2a8030b7aa5f2762a464bf7f8b0c7/c4x/BerkeleyX/CEGA101AIE/asset/Module_2.5_Difference_in_Differences.pdf That's why I am confused.

Comment: you invited me to answer this question, but I don't know very much about panel models/econometric approaches, so it would take a lot of effort for me ...

Comment: I *think* I know what you wanted to do, but I'm slightly uncertain. Here is why. You said you want to do PSM with the first equation you show, but PSM is 2 steps with the PS being the regression then the M coming 2nd. I guess your 1st equation was your PS regression, right? Then by "diff in diff" did you mean matching to estimate something like ATT or ATE, which is how PSM normally works, or did you mean a diff-in-diff model?

Comment: Another thing - while I think this package is interesting, it looks like it's focused on time-series/panel versions of the PSM analysis - is this what you're going for? If so, do you know what lags, etc, you wanted? If not, I suggest to use `Matching` or `FastMatch`, the traditional PSM packages that are not focused on time-series (I have some tutorials online and could show you how).

Comment: Sorry, 1 more note - the equation specified `leverage` and `loss` but I don't see a column named that in the example data

Comment: I have added an answer below. Once you have read it and my comments if your question is answered then I will delete the comments above.

Comment: @Hack-R First, I thank you very much for sharing your time and knowledge. The variable with the title "switch" is used as treatment. The variable named "date" is considered as time id. Besides, unit id is shown by "id". In the first stage, I should match treated and control companies using the variables "big4", "lnasset", "leverage", and "loss". In the second stage, I should do difference in difference on the previous stage matched sample using the second equation. Therefore, by diff in diff, I mean difference in difference model.

Comment: I want to know if auditor switching affects the cost of debt. In other words, if the debt cost of companies after switching would be greater than before  for companies which have switched their auditors? That's why I first want to match switched and control companies. Then, I want to use diff in diff model. Since I am dealing with time series cross sectional data set, I need to use PanelMatch or maybe CBPS package.

Comment: Sorry, I uploaded the dataset here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ujteiwp0jqrtip4/psm1.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Just wanted to check with you should not the matching be done year wise as treatment varies

Comment: @ebrahimi The `PanelMatch` package already offers simple diagnostics by allowing you to examine covariate balance over the pre-period. Why not use what's already available?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it. Please see the questions and comment I left above.

Based on the question it seemed like the choice of the newer non-CRAN panel matching library `PanelMatch`, while interesting, seemed to require information/data not in your question for time-series specific use cases of PSM.

It sounded like you're in the more general case, wherein you'd want a plain PSM/matching package like `Matching` or `FastMatch`, though if this assumption is incorrect please let me know and provide more info on your needs.

Ok so first, load the libraries and data:

```
#devtools::install_github("insongkim/PanelMatch", dependencies=TRUE)

if ( !require(pacman) ) install.packages("pacman");require(pacman)
p_load(Matching,speedglm) # PanelMatch

data <- read.table(text="id date lnaudten big4 altmanz lnasset lnage    mtob     lev    prof   tang   cavol  switch decost los
1  86  .693147    0   18.4373 12.4689 2.48491 3.69137 .051575 .44427  .999581 .195047  0 .205964  0
                   1  87  1.09861    0   12.5244 12.7628 2.56495 2.69891 .043572 .559291 .999688 .128583  0 .107817  0
                   1  88  1.38629    0   14.7922 13.3187 2.63906 3.55144 .037377 .901665 .99897  .045367  0 .085176  0
                   1  89  1.60944    0   21.6806 13.5282 2.70805 4.4521  .090386 1.00277 .998904 .034365  0 .059932  0
                   1  90  1.79176    0   16.6034 13.7204 2.77259 3.16585 .077934 1.21371 .999292 .032229  0 .064589  0
                   1  91  0          0   9.32285 14.0652 2.83321 1.87682 .038984 1.61792 .999376 .019715  1 .086323  0
                   1  92  .693147    0   29.1306 14.3805 2.89037 3.83173 .030874 3.42558 .999687 .117503  0 .148985  0
                   1  93  1.09861    0   23.7929 14.5855 2.94444 3.08877 .01225  4.19413 .999862 .171374  0 .181363  0
                   2  86  1.94591    1   2.67142 13.5351 1.60944 .90438  .031392 .284566 .997711 .172729  0 .116186  0
                   2  87  2.07944    1   1.85554 13.6068 1.79176 .783169 .037099 .28575  .997862 .055812  0 .137087  0
                   2  88  2.19723    1   3.25227 13.6162 1.94591 .857463 .046493 .264266 .99788  .052991  0 .174771  0
                   2  89  2.30258    1   2.46358 13.8247 2.07944 1.00449 .045589 .246997 .998208 .064097  0 .168786  0
                   2  90  2.3979     1   1.43551 13.8304 2.19723 .791431 .060575 .171494 .998218 .062911  0 .240464  0
                   2  91  0          0   1.10687 13.7423 2.30258 .532189 .071249 .164944 .998054 .093181  1 .351773  0
                   2  92  .693147    0   3.39252 13.8668 2.3979  1.80869 .121138 .177533 .998281 .090341  0 .282046  0
                   2  93  1.09861    0   3.95825 14.0244 2.48491 1.41083 .094626 .162305 .99847  .134091  0 .188627  0
                   3  86  .693147    0   5.01935 13.0392 3.49651 1.08849 .008833 .275658 .995814 .165765  0 .12684   0
                   3  87  1.09861    0   8.51978 13.0429 3.52636 .794968 .010574 .349996 .995351 .276396  0 2.49701  0
                   3  88  1.38629    0   13.1943 13.2777 3.55535 1.36713 .043884 .409195 .996392 .079824  0 .033575  0
                   3  89  1.60944    0   18.7427 13.4562 3.58352 1.89782 .010373 .42366  .997045 .049833  0 .057621  0
                   3  90  1.79176    0   20.2185 13.4667 3.61092 1.69264 .016154 .339384 .997148 .133837  0 .133177  0
                   3  91  0          0   11.1153 13.9098 3.63759 1.50931 .010464 .935899 .998216 .12095   1 .089572  0
                   3  92  .693147    0   25.7134 14.1341 3.66356 2.41058 .004609 1.06214 .99856  .13175   0 .171943  0
                   3  93  1.09861    0   29.8983 14.162  3.68888 2.29729 .003891 .902802 .997648 .146949  0 .823985  0",
                   header = T)

head(data)
```

I am taking the PS equation from your question, but normally I use the 
   `MatchBalance()` function and its statistical tests to define the
   PS model specification

Your equation mentioned leverage and loss, but it's missing from the data,
     so I will exclude that below.

Here's the propensity score (PS) model:

```
form <- as.formula("switch ~ big4 + lnasset")

mod  <- speedglm::speedglm(
  form,
  family=binomial(),
  fitted=T,
  data = data
)
summary(mod) # note poor fit, but I will ignore this for the example
```

OK, now extract the propensity scores:

```
data$fitted.values <- predict(mod)
```

Now do matching, and calculate quasi-experimental statistics,
    like Average effect of Treatment on the Treated (ATT) or the ATE:

```
set.seed(1) # set a random seed 
atta <- Match(  Y        = data$decost, # I assume this is the outcome 
            Tr       = data$switch, # Treatment/Control indicator
                X        = data$fitted.values, # PS's
                estimand = "ATT", # Outcome metric
                M        = 1, # 1-to-1 or 1-to-many matching
                ties     = F,#T, # T = VERY SLOW but higher quality
                replace  = TRUE,
                exact    = T,
                version  = "fast" )
summary(atta)  #
```

That gives you your result. You should also do post hoc testing to make sure that treatment and control are NOT significantly different on any control variables.